# Customize how "Find in Folder..." works for Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

After you right click a folder in a Sublime Text 2 project, then select "Find in Folder...", it's this menu:

[image]

How can you change the output of when the user clicks "Find" on the right to just show the file names, and not the text inside those files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 has Goto Anything (**Ctrl+P** on Windows and Linux, Command+P on OS X) to quickly navigate between and within files:

1. **Type part of a file name to open it.**
2. Type an ‘@’ character, and start browsing by symbol.
3. Type ‘#’ to search within the file, or ‘:’ to go to a line number.

see [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-2-public-alpha) for more info

Comment: I second that. Find in folder is not intended at all to find filenames.

Comment: @ByScripts Indeed it's not. it's handy to know the shortcuts!